# C# Ignore inside of speech, while changing other values

Tags: c#, string

I am trying to make a basic translator, which changes values in the code, for example, a `.` may be `::`, e.t.c, and I can do that by using

```
if(code.Contains("."))
{
      code.Replace(".", "::");
}
```

But my problem is I don't know how to ignore it in the inside of speech, as if the sentence was "Hello.", it could be translated to "Hello::". How would I be able to stop this? (I know you can use Regex `"\".+?\""` to find speech in text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do here is vastly more complicated than you realise.

Programming languages differ in more than just appearance, they have different capabilities and syntax rules, even for two as similar as C# and C++. Aside from the fact that the C# . is equivalent to . -> and :: in C++. There's also different rules regarding pointers, and sometimes you get issues like having a pointer to a pointer, not to mention that the * and & symbols can be binary arithmetic/logic operations or pointer operations depending on their use. There's also issues involving keywords such as const, auto and sizeof.

In short, unless you're prepared to write a proper tokeniser, you aren't going to pull this off properly. To properly translate one programming language to another you would at least have to write a good chunk of a full compiler, which is a specialist subject.

I suggest you do some research into tokenisers and lexical analysis before you go any further.

As a hint though, you'll find it easier to split your code up into an array of characters and handle one character at a time whilst keeping track of the program's state (ie are you currently in the middle of a string, are you in the middle of two brackets, how many levels of nesting have you come across). By doing it that way you can at least manage to change the surface-level differences (as opposed to deeper ones like keywords and typing).

EDIT:

Some useful resources for writing tokenisers and compilers:
http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~pjj/farrell/comp3.html
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/3yx2xe3h(v=vs.100).aspx
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Compiler_Construction/Lexical_analysis

I speak from experience, as I did recently attempt to write my own compiler (in C#), but put the project on hold due to more important matters getting in the way.

Comment: It's my own programming language, and it's pretty basic to translate. Thanks anyway: it's a very useful answer, it may come in useful one day

Comment: @Joe In that case you will definitely want to write a tokeniser. Even interpreted languages use them.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use a regex to help you out here, but it would be fairly complex and perform poorly. You could also just do this:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
bool insideSpeech = false;
foreach(char c in code) {
    if(c == '"') {
        insideSpeech = !insideSpeech;
    }
    if(c == '.' && !insideSpeech) {
        sb.Append("::");
    } else {
        sb.Append(c);
    }
}
code = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: The line `sb.Append(code[i]);` is wrong because you are using the for loop any more, you are using a foreach loop. It should be `sb.Append(c);`